# podman "/bin/sh: 1: ./runModel.sh: not found"

Tags: bash, sh, podman

I have a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq build-essential autoconf libnetcdf-dev libxml2-dev libproj-dev valgrind wget unzip git nano

# pulls ADBM from github and unzips in folder ADMBcode
RUN mkdir /ADMBcode 
RUN wget https://github.com/admb-project/admb/releases/download/admb-12.2/admb-12.2-linux.zip
RUN mv admb-12.2-linux.zip /ADMBcode
RUN unzip ADMBcode/admb-12.2-linux.zip -d /ADMBcode

# pulls hydra repo from github into folder HYDRA
RUN mkdir /HYDRA
RUN git clone https://github.com/NOAA-EDAB/hydra_sim.git /HYDRA

WORKDIR /HYDRA

# incase of windows stuff
RUN chmod -R 777 /HYDRA
   
# compile the model
RUN /ADMBcode/admb-12.2/admb hydra_sim.tpl


CMD ./runModel.sh
```

It installs software, pulls from Github, and compiles a model, then it should execute a shell script.

If i use the command

```
podman run imageName
```

then all seems to run ok. i can enter the container and type ./runModel.sh and i can confirm the model runs.

But if i type

```
podman run --mount "type=bind,src=/path_to_input_files/,dst=/HYDRA/" imageName
```

where the `path_to_input_files` contains two files `hydra_sim.dat` and `hydra_sim.pin` i get the error

`/bin/sh: 1: ./runModel.sh: not found`

This file (`runModel.sh`) exists in the WORKDIR (it is part of the cloned repo). But if i add it to the `path_to_input_files` directory that is mounted i still get the same error.

What am i missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run:

```
podman run --mount "type=bind,src=/path_to_input_files/,dst=/HYDRA/" imageName
```

You are *replacing* the contents of `/HYDRA` with the contents of `/path_to_input_files`. Anything else that was included in that directory in the image is no longer accessible.

That means in particular that `/HYDRA/runModel.sh` is not available.

The fix is to mount your input files at another location.